# Laravel 5 ,Table not updating

Tags: php, laravel-5

[image][image][image]Im Trying to update my table through Laravel Updation,i get no error when i tried to print the result i just got an null value ,i have pasted my model and controller.

controller

```
     public function update_FAQ_submit()
                        {

         $data      = Input::except(array(
            '_token'
        ));
        $rule      = array(
            'faq_ques' => 'required',
            'faq_ans' => 'required'

        );
        $id        = Input::get('id');
        $validator = Validator::make($data, $rule);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return Redirect::to('Coin_lion/FAQ')->withErrors($validator->messages())->withInput();

        } else {
            $entry = array(
                'faq_ques' => Input::get('faq_ques'),
                'faq_ans' => Input::get('faq_ans')

            );

            $faq=FAQ::update_faq($id, $entry);

            return Redirect::to('Coin_lion/manage_FAQ');
        }
                    }
```

Model

```
public static function update_faq($id, $entry)
{

    return DB::table('faq')->where('id', '=', $id)->update($entry);



}
```

Routes:

```
Route::post('Coin_lion/update_FAQ_submit','AdminController@update_FAQ_submit');
```

my DB

My form
 here is my form ,i have included what method i used previously
    
    ">
    {!! Form::hidden('id', $id) !!}
    @foreach ($faq as $info)

```
<label>Enter your question:</label><br>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="faq_ques" value="<?php echo $info->faq_ques ?>"><br>
 <label>Enter your Answer:</label>
      <textarea  class="form-control" name="faq_ans" cols="10" rows="5" ><?php echo $info->faq_ans ?></textarea> 

      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="submit" value="ADD">
<input type="reset" class="btn btn-danger" name="submit" value="Cancel">
@endforeach
</body>
```

Comment: Did you check `Input::get(..` values?

Comment: yes the values are getting printed ,but when i tried  this query in controller after getting the inputs
                    $faq=FAQ::update_faq($id, $entry);
                             print_r($faq);
                           die();           i get 0 as output

Comment: Check database table. Is it have id `id` and this collumns `faq_ques` and `faq_ans`

Comment: yes check the db pic

Comment: Input::get('id') value?

Comment: Your route describes the method as 'POST' but you are loading the route to try execute it. i.e you are doing a GET on a POST route

Comment: @J.Litvak id value is not displaying

Comment: @ochhii could you explain more i coudnt understand

Comment: You call controller from browser url? or from ajax?

Comment: Browser @J.Litvak

Comment: @AmalJo Sure. You are trying to call the method AdminController@update_FAQ_submit. In your route, you defined the way to access this method with Route::post(...) so you can only perform this method with a POST request to /Coin_lion/update_FAQ_submit. Opening the url in your web browser is a GET request.

Comment: Method in form is `post`?

Comment: <form method="post" action="{{ action('AdminController@update_FAQ_submit') }}"> YES @j.litvalk

Comment: check `id` value in `form`

Comment: the id is getting null value

Comment: Please add the code for the form you are using. Your question at the moment seems as though you aren't even using a form.

Answer (score 0):

First try to check that you are getting values in your controller and passing it correctly in you model then you need to replace your query with this. And replace your model code with this.

```
     public function update_faq($id, $entry)
     {
      DB::table('faq')->where('id',$id)->update($entry);
     }
```

Comment: Nothing changed

Comment: check again i removed the static

Comment: Are you getting the id and entry inside your route when you hit it try to print it first

Comment: entry is getting but id is null i.e no value showing

Answer (score 0):

```
public static function update_faq($id, $entry) {
    DB::table('faq')
            ->where('id', $id)  // find your faq by their id
            ->update($entry);  // update the record in the DB.
}
```

Comment: always strive to post a description with every answer.